# Axios http request in Firebase App - 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) version 0.13.1 and if I want to get data with `orderBy` and `limitToFirst` parameters, I got 400 Bad request error.

With this http request I get 400 error:

```
axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://tracker-ag.firebaseio.com/groups.json',
        params: {
            auth: AccessStore.getToken(),
            orderBy: "$key",
            limitToFirst: 2,
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        responseHandler(USERS_GET, '', response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error during fetching data " + error.message);
    });
```

This http request without orderBy and limitToFirst parameters works:

```
axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://tracker-ag.firebaseio.com/groups.json',
    params: {
        auth: AccessStore.getToken(),
    }
}).then(function (response) {
    responseHandler(USERS_GET, '', response.data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error during fetching data " + error.message);
});
```